# ApplicationContext.getAppContext().getBean("jBeanName") return null in Junit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, applicationcontext

I do have  this simple class annotated with `@Configuration`

```
@ConfigurationProperties("sample")
@Configuration
public class Sample {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String url; 

//Implementation }
```

In order to get my web app beans file, I created  this class

```
@Component
public class AppSpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * Returns the Spring managed bean instance of the given class type if it exists.
     * Returns null otherwise.
     *
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

        // Store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
        AppSpringContext.context = context;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }

}
```

When I tried to instantiate the sample class in the  test class I got a null pointer exception although I was able  to instantiate it successfully in the  main class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {



    private Sample getInstance(Sample cfg) {

        if (cfg == null) {
            cfg = (Sample) AppSpringContext.getAppContext().getBean("sample"); //returns  NULL object
        }
        return cfg; }

//Rest of  implementation

}
```

Any help plzz ??

Comment: How did you confirm `Sample` bean got created ? What happens when you annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest` ?

Answer (score -1):

change `@ConfigurationProperties("sample") @Configuration`

Comment: to `@Component`

Comment: I am using `@ConfigurationProperties("sample")`  to import properties  from appl.prop file, `@Configuration` is meta-annotated with `@Component`, therefore `@Configuration` classes are candidates for component scanning, in short `@Configuration` is also a `@Component` but a `@Component` cannot act like a `@Cofinguration`